# Django - html not extending meta tags

Tags: python, html, django, extends

I have a base.html file from where I extend other pages. I have this code in my  base.html:

base.html

```
<html lang="es-es">
<head>
<title>
    Home - {% block titulo %}{% endblock %}
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="/static/style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

All the templates extending from base.html have some spanish words and symbols and I have to put this meta tag again (so it doesn't throw me a unicode error), even when is on the base.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
```

Aren't the templates supposed to inherit all the tags from the parent template? What is it that I'm doing wrong?

**--EDIT 16 Mar 2016--**

This is one example of a child. For the view I'm using: `ListView.as_view` in the url file, but not all the files extending from the base are using the same method although I do have to insert the meta tags in all the files for accents and other symbols to work.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

<!--The next 2 lines after this comment 
are in every html files that extends from the base file
 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

{% block titulo %}
Lideres
{% endblock%}
{% block content %}
<h2>Listado de Teléfonos</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should show the child template, and the view.

Comment: One possibility: you either can move the `meta` tag to before the title (if you have a really long title, the HTML parser may not see the meta tag due to the [1024 byte limit](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset)) or you can specify your content type directly in your [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects).

Comment: moving the meta tags before the title did not worked. Please check the new info I posted and let me know if I'm doing something wrong o not doing something I should do. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What about the Django view? Also what do you mean when you say Unicode error? Is this a Python exception? If so can you post the exception?

Comment: I'm using ListView.as_view. And the error is:

`UnicodeDecodeError at /ver_lideres
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 417: invalid continuation byte
Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: h>Tel�fono<`